# Lightweight text indexing api library for Android

Tags: android, api, search

I've found Lucene, but the binary is 25Mb and my app is 300K. :( I'd like to index some files when the user does a custom search in my app through the Android system search. As for now, I'm doing a simple string match on the content of the files, and scan all directories for files each time. Is there a search api that would do indexing and possibly filter out stopwords to speed the search up?

Answer (score 2):

Hi you should read the documentation page below. The related part is "Searching your data"

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

it says that you should use FTS3 extension of SQLite database.

Comment: I'm not using an SQLite database. I'm trying to index files and their contents (more precisely the exif data information on photos) and make them searchable quickly.

Comment: Then put data to sqlite and it will be automatically indexed. It is officially supported so it won't be a problem for you to implement.